# How to Prevent mach_ports_register() from failing in Java on OSX

Tags: java, macos, selenium

I have a program that uses java and selenium to randomly log into a webpage every 20-30 seconds, and make a post on that website. After around an hour and a half, I start to see the following:

```
mach_ports_register() failed! XPC will not work in the child process: 0x10004002: (ipc/rcv) invalid name
mach_ports_register() failed! XPC will not work in the child process: 0x10004002: (ipc/rcv) invalid name
```

How do I prevent this from happening? Do I have to free up my ports or memory or something?
I am trying to get this to run for at least 10 days without any problems.